# jQuery Template, {{if}} with a passed string

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using a jQuery template like so:

```
<script type="text/html" id="ListTemplate">
{{if (parseInt($.attachment_count) > 0) }}
    XXXX
{{else}}
    ${attachment_count}
{{/if}}

</script>
```

But this does not work? The if block never returns true. Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think the parenthesis are necessary, but they shouldn't cause any issues. Maybe there's an issue with your code inside the `{{if}}` block?

Should

```
{{if (parseInt($.attachment_count) > 0) }}
```

be:

```
{{if (parseInt(attachment_count) > 0) }}
```

Where `attachment_count` is a property of the object the template is rendering?

Additionally, you can actually write `console` statements in jQuery templates:

```
${console.log($item)}
```

The template engine will render `undefined` on your template, but you'll be able to inspect template variables through the console. This can be helpful because sometimes those templates can be difficult to debug.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Especially the additional console.log suggestion is pretty useful. Thumbs up.